# How can I find files of multiple types using an or statement?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, find

I can't seem to find this on StackOverflow by searching. How can I find all files of type `.html` and `.py`?

I'm trying `find ./ -name *.py or *.html -type f`

But this is returning `find: or: unknown primary or operator`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ find . -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp'.
```

or `find . -type f \( -name "*.class" -o -name "*.sh" \)`